# Save vectors from loop into a list or data.frame R

Tags: r, list, loops, vector

I have to generate several iterations of some mathematical operations, which result in a vector of length 100 each time. I want to store each vector of n iterations into a list or data frame after running a for loop. Basically, I want to save my results (a vector of length 100) into a list to be converted into a matrix or directly into a matrix.

For instance:

```
for (i in 1:10){
     r <- rnorm(100,0,1)
     }
```

In each of the 10 iterations, R generates a vector of length 100. The final desired output is a data frame with 100 rows and 10 columns, each column representing each of the generated iterations. How can one build such a matrix or data frame?

Comment: `replicate(10, rnorm(100,0,1))` or `matrix(rnorm(10*100,0,1), ncol=10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for` loop you can do

```
# choose number of columns you need
ncolumns <- 10
# generate an "empty" matrix
m <- matrix(NA, 100, ncolumns)
# run for loop
for (i in 1:ncolumns){
  m[ , i] <- rnorm(100,0,1)
}
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the m matrix empy with NAs. I dont know why. This is the same approach I tried but the matrix got always empty...

Comment: @EmilioMármolSánchez You copy-pasted the code above and get an empty m? That is strange, I get random numbers in m.

Comment: ***Why is this downvoted?*** I don't argue for using a `for` loop and personally, I prefer the soluation of Ronak Shash but the question contains `for` loop and I wanted to explain how it works.

Comment: You can use the recycling rule: `matrix(NA, 100, ncolumns)`

Comment: @jogo Like that one! Used it in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `replicate`

```
replicate(10, rnorm(100))
```

If needed we can convert it into a dataframe (showing a smaller example for `n = 5`)

```
set.seed(1234)
as.data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(5)))

#       V1      V2       V3      V4      V5       V6      V7      V8      V9     V10
#1 -1.2071  0.5061 -0.47719 -0.1103  0.1341 -1.44820  1.1023 -1.1676  1.4495 -0.9685
#2  0.2774 -0.5747 -0.99839 -0.5110 -0.4907  0.57476 -0.4756 -2.1800 -1.0686 -1.1073
#3  1.0844 -0.5466 -0.77625 -0.9112 -0.4405 -1.02366 -0.7094 -1.3410 -0.8554 -1.2520
#4 -2.3457 -0.5645  0.06446 -0.8372  0.4596 -0.01514 -0.5013 -0.2943 -0.2806 -0.5238
#5  0.4291 -0.8900  0.95949  2.4158 -0.6937 -0.93595 -1.6291 -0.4659 -0.9943 -0.4968
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I spent a long time finding a simple way of doing this and this way is surprisingly simple compared to the other options I've seen so far.